# Fetching last value from a comma separated string

Tags: vb.net

i am new to VB.
I am trying to retrieve the last value in the csv below.

0066,0055,0078

From this string, I want to fetch 0078.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*From this string, I want to fetch 0078.*

Try this,

```
Dim xString as String = "0066,0055,0078"
Dim xResult() as String = xString.split(",")
Dim xExtracted as String = xResult(xResult.length-1)

MsgBox(xExtracted)
```

Comment: Thanks Raja, I tried the same and getting a compiler error as "option strict On disallows late binding".

Comment: @user2957476 what is the error you are getting.?

Comment: compiler error as "option strict On disallows late binding

Comment: @user2957476 I just updated my code, Try this out.

Comment: Perfect Sir ! It did work

Comment: @user2957476 Glad to help. :) don't forget to mark this as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

a shorter alternative would be:

```
Dim xString as String = "0066,0055,0078"
MsgBox(xString.Substring(xString.LastIndexOf(",") + 1))
```

if you are going to use the function regularly consider creating an extension method